# How to manage files of link source by git?

Tags: linux, git

## Want

I wanna manage nvim config by git.

## Problem

Link is break by `git checkout .` command. Expect behavior is overwrite my nvim config with remote repository source. But actual behavior is overwrite link with remote repository source.

## Code

I was tried as bellow code.

```sh
# clone
cd ~/Documents/GitHub/
git clone https://github.com/ShortArrow/my-nvim-config
cd my-nvim-config

# delete "./nvim" for making link
rm -r ./nvim
# making link
ln -s ~/.config/nvim/ ./nvim

# if you need, "cp ~/.config/nvim/ ~/.config/nvim-backup"
# I wanna rewrite nvim config by git with this command
git checkout .
```

## Already Tried

try1

```sh
sudo git config --system --unset core.symlinks
git config --local core.symlinks false
```

try2

```
$> sudo ln -d ~/.config/nvim/ ./nvim
ln: failed to create hard link './nvim' => '/home/who/.config/nvim/': Operation not permitted
```

## On Windows

This github repository is working good with Junction link on Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A softlink is just a file with the target path in it (and a permission flag telling the OS to treat it as a link), and Git is treating it as such.

Instead of changing what is in the repository by changing the repository file into a link to the config file, **link the other way**: make the *config file* link *into the repository*.

Comment: When specifying a local repository as the source of a symbolic link, it must be specified as an absolute path. It is good to be careful about this. 

Like this, `sudo ln -s /home/who/Documents/GitHub/my-nvim-config/nvim/   ~/.config/nvim`. 

Bad case is `cd my-nvim-config && sudo ln -s ./nvim/   ~/.config/nvim`. This is return error message `too many levels of symbolic links` when `ls ~/.config/nvim` command.